# On the Lemma 39.1. of the Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

During the proof of Lemma 39.1. of the Munkres' Topology, it is written "In general $\bigcup \bar A \subset \bar {\bigcup A}$." But it is not so obvious to me to prove it.

Simple detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only want to give a hint: From $A\subseteq\bigcup A$, we deduce that $\bar A\subseteq \overline{\bigcup A}$.

Comment: İ cant believe how easy it was.. Thank you.